# Setting arbitrary PHP constants in index.php

Tags: variable, php, index

I was looking for a way to set arbitrary PHP constants in the index.php that could then be accessed within templates.

This is particularly useful if you have more than one index/domain pulling content from a core Craft install as the additional domains won't have any configuration files to use, just index.php.

Answer (score 5):

*Hat-tip to Brad for finding this answer.*

This can be achieved with something like the following in your index.php:

```
define('BRADS_FAVORITE_HOBBY', "Drinking");
```

Thanks to the [power to Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/constant.html), you can then access this in your templates using:

```
{{ constant('BRADS_FAVORITE_HOBBY') }}
```

Comment: Very useful in certain cases, indeed. Thanks for sharing, Steve.